# Получить изображение с удаленного адреса

Tags: javascript

Нужно реализовать загрузку фотографии в профиль по удаленной ссылке. Сперва я должен получить изображение на фронтенде, чтобы валидировать и кропать.

Пробовал через канвас, пробовал через аджакс скачать, и получаю ошибку безопасности "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header...".

Можно ли как-то безопасно на Jquery получить изображение на фронтенде, чтобы потом перегнать в бейс64, отредактировать, создать блоб обьект и отправить на сервер?

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь на js тебе не позволит скачать картинку с другого домена, так же как управлять файловой структурой на локальной машине из за безопасности, о чем тебе в принципе и пишут =)

Comment: Та да, решил отправлять на бекенд ссылку, получать там бейс64, возвращать его без сохранения на фронт для кропа и т.п., и уже далее слать Blob обьект для бэкэнд валидации и сохранения на сервере

Comment: Для использования кросс-доменных запросов нужно [постучать в бубен](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8163703/cross-domain-ajax-doesnt-send-x-requested-with-header). Но, если не страшно получить кучу запросов от ботов, лучше так не делать...